# Getting NewsId with Lead Paragraph and web_url using Cosine Similarity

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

I am trying to get recommended news_id with its lead_paragraph and web_url using cosine similarity .
My Data Set has 3 columns news_id,lead_paragraph,web_url

The following code only return recommended news_id

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy 
ds = pd.read_csv("nytimes.csv") 

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')


ds['lead_paragraph'] = ds['lead_paragraph'].fillna('')


tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(ds['lead_paragraph'])

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel


cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

indices = pd.Series(ds.index, index=ds['_id']).drop_duplicates()

def get_recommendations(id, cosine_sim=cosine_sim):

    idx = indices[id]
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)


   sim_scores = sim_scores[1:11]


  movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]


return ds['_id'].iloc[movie_indices]

get_recommendations('4fd2b43e8eb7c8105d8a67e8')
```

How to get recommended news_id's  with their lead_paragraph and web_url in the list ?